# After adding react-native-chrome-cast I get the error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I'm trying to add the [react-native-google-cast](https://github.com/react-native-google-cast/react-native-google-cast) to my project but everytime I build the android project I get the error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-google- cast:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

where the first error is:

```
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
/Users/../GoogleCastActivity.java:14: error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Its been driving me absolutley insnane, I've also added an issue on the reposity [here](https://github.com/react-native-google-cast/react-native-google-cast/issues/131) a couple days ago.

Things that I have tried:

- Adding `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'` to the build.gradle file which is suggested in a lot of SO posts that mention `error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist`
- Installing on projects with different versions of react native - Installing it on RN0.57 worked perfectly but I am trying to install it on RN0.60 as some of the other packages I plan on using require a newer version of reactnative
- Completed their installion guide in their README.md on their github a fair few times and gone through their troubleshooting section

  - Their trouble shooting section of their [v4 branch](https://github.com/react-native-google-cast/react-native-google-cast/tree/v4#troubleshooting) mentions:

  > Android: If you're having version conflicts of the appcompat (or
  >   google play services) libraries, make sure you set versions globally
  >   in your project's top-level build.gradle:
  >
  > ```
  > buildscript {   
  >   ext {
  >     buildToolsVersion = '27.0.3'
  >     minSdkVersion = 16
  >     compileSdkVersion = 27
  >     targetSdkVersion = 26
  >     supportLibVersion = '26.1.0'
  >     castFrameworkVersion = '16.1.2'   }
  > ... }
  > ```

  But I had no luck with trying that

These are the versions I am using:

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.3",
"react-native-google-cast": "^3.1.3"
```

Please let me know if there is any other relevant information I have missed, any help is greatly greatly appreciated!!

Comment: don't use '+', instead include appcompat support library as com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0. If possible use androix support libraries. Android Studio->Refactor->Migrate To AndroidX'

Comment: @RanjanKumar sadly no luck trying that :( - Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: What is the error when you tried converting support libraries to androidX?

Comment: @RanjanKumar the same as above

Comment: Alfie, can you invalidate cache and make clean build. If androidX support library is used, then it shall give error for package 'androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity'

Comment: @RanjanKumar ah okay, so if I open `node_modules/react-native-google-cast/android` in android studio and try to migrate to androidX I get the error `No usages found in the project` and if I open the android folder in the root folder of the react-native project I still get the same error in the question (i invalidated the cache both times before as well)